# What's the legality of official musics being remix by indie artists?

Tags: copyright

I want to know if it's illegal to sell remix musics based on a popular song. Because I found many independent artists remixing a popular song and selling it on iTunes.

Look at these examples: 
   [Written in the stars](http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/written-in-the-stars-feat/id432983250)
   [Never say never](http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/never-say-never-feat-megan/id420998559)

These musics are written by major recordings, but why are they allowed to sell it in iTunes?

Answer (score 1):

Start with page 3 of this:

[Mashups, Remixes, and Copyright Law](http://eprints.qut.edu.au/4239/1/4239.pdf)

The short answer is that unless they obtained a license or permission of the performing artists AND they paid the Harry Fox Agency for the compositions themselves, it is technically illegal. iTunes has no responsibility to police content for copyright violations. That's what attorneys and cease and desist letters are for.